# How do I place a text with background color on a picture?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place the text with the brown background color on a the picture but it always appears under the picture. I put both the picture and the text in the same div but still nothing

https://jsfiddle.net/Gsimelus92/5xp3sr96/

```
<section class="part-a">
   <div class="container">
      <img src="pizza.jpg" width="1550" height="1000" alt="pizza">
      <div class="container-text">
         <h1>Our Food</h1>
         <h2>Take a look</h2>
         <p>We do all naturel flavors and spices</p>
         <button>Show me the menu</button>
         <button>Boot a Table</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp).

Answer (score 2):

try with this

```
.container-text{
    position: absolute;;
    background-color: #AA8A45;
    color:white;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```